# POP up appears without clicking the Link

Tags: java, selenium

[image]I'm automating [this site:](https://services.aviva.ie/direct/product/car.htm?_flowId=motor-flow&_flowExecutionKey=e5s1)

When I click a button a pop up is displayed. There is a link on the screen to display the pop-up but I don't have anything in my code to click the link this code is commented out.

```
 //Please click to confirm you read and accept the conditions
    driver.findElement(By.id("assumptionsConfirmed1")).click();
```

Comment: it seems that it is not commented out... just add `//` right before `driver.`

Comment: The code in my question is the code for the button not for the link.

Comment: What's your question? You stated a popup appears but never indicate what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with xpath i think this might work for you bcz i have seen in resources and xpath look more better than id.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'assumptions and terms and conditions before procee')]")).click();
```